# How can I dump the text of laws from a CSV file with odd characters in the names into a folder as JSON files?

Tags: python, json, request

I am trying to work through a csv that contains names of laws and a link to the law itself. I would like to access each of the links and dump the text of the law into a folder as a json file. I think the problem might have something to do with the odd characters in the law names but I am unsure.

```
import csv
import json
import requests
import os
from urllib.parse import quote

data_from_supa = 'book1.csv'
current_directory = os.getcwd()
output_folder = os.path.join(current_directory, 'json_files')

def save_doc_as_json(citation, citation_url):
    encoded_url = quote(citation_url, safe="/:")  # Encode the URL
    response = requests.get(encoded_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        json_data = response.json()
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, citation + ".json")

        with open(output_file_path, "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(json_data, json_file)

with open(data_from_supa, "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for row in csv_reader:
        file_name = row["citation"]
        link = row["citation_url"]

        save_doc_as_json(file_name, link)
```

The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/allisonkroboth/Desktop/resilience_data_project/retrive_docs.py", line 28, in <module>
    save_doc_as_json(file_name, link)
  File "/Users/allisonkroboth/Desktop/resilience_data_project/retrive_docs.py", line 15, in save_doc_as_json
    json_data = response.json()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```